# click event for nvd3 chart (as a custom output binding) in a shiny application

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, nvd3.js

**EDIT:**

Solved the issue: `.useInteractiveGuideline(true)` changed to  `.useInteractiveGuideline(false)`

**ORIGINAL:**

I am trying to modify the custom output binding [example](https://github.com/jcheng5/shiny-js-examples/tree/master/output) using an NVD3 line chart with attaching a click event listener to the NVD3 chart. I modified the `linechart-bindings.js` file as follows. The only modification is this part of the code (the whole file is also copied below so you can see there i added the snippet):

```
    chart.lines.dispatch.on("elementClick", function( e ) {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

The app starts without problem, but there is no console log printout when i click the chart. Probably my approach is too simplistic and there is some obvious part missing. Any idea how to solve this?

The full `linechar-bindings.js` file:

```
// Put code in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE).
// This isn't strictly necessary, but it's good JavaScript hygiene.
(function() {

// See http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#building-outputs for
// more information on creating output bindings.

// First create a generic output binding instance, then overwrite
// specific methods whose behavior we want to change.
var binding = new Shiny.OutputBinding();

binding.find = function(scope) {
  // For the given scope, return the set of elements that belong to
  // this binding.
  return $(scope).find(".nvd3-linechart");
};

binding.renderValue = function(el, data) {
  // This function will be called every time we receive new output
  // values for a line chart from Shiny. The "el" argument is the
  // div for this particular chart.

  var $el = $(el);

  // The first time we render a value for a particular element, we
  // need to initialize the nvd3 line chart and d3 selection. We'll
  // store these on $el as a data value called "state".
  if (!$el.data("state")) {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
      .margin({left: 100})
      .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
      .transitionDuration(350)
      .showLegend(true)
      .showYAxis(true)
      .showXAxis(true);

    chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings
      .axisLabel('Time (ms)')
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

    chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
      .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
      .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

    chart.lines.dispatch.on("elementClick", function( e ) {
        console.log(e);
    });

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    var selection = d3.select(el).select("svg");

    // Store the chart object on el so we can get it next time
    $el.data("state", {
      chart: chart,
      selection: selection
    });
  }

  // Now, the code that'll run every time a value is rendered...

  // Retrieve the chart and selection we created earlier
  var state = $el.data("state");

  // Schedule some work with nvd3
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    // Update the chart
    state.selection
      .datum(data)
      .transition(500)
      .call(state.chart);
    return state.chart;
  });
};

// Tell Shiny about our new output binding
Shiny.outputBindings.register(binding, "shinyjsexamples.nvd3-linechart");

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround:
`.useInteractiveGuideline(true)` changed to `.useInteractiveGuideline(false)`